# public Task Connect() not firing when user connects to hub class

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have the following hub class:

```
public class Dashboard : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
    {
        //Initialize Repoisotries 
        private IProfileRepository profileRepository;
        private ISiteDataRepository siteDataRepository;
        private readonly IHubContext matchContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MatchMaker>();

    //Constructor Injection for profile repository and site data repository
    public Dashboard(IProfileRepository repo, ISiteDataRepository siteRepo)
    {            
        profileRepository = repo;
        siteDataRepository = siteRepo;            
    }
    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> connections)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public Task Connect()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(MatchMaker.onlineUsers.Count);
        return null;
    }
    public void GetUserInfo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(MatchMaker.onlineUsers.Count);
    }
}
```

}

I have the signalr include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I access it like so:

```
$(function () {
    //Create the proxy
    var Dashboard = $.connection.dashboard;
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        Dashboard.getUserInfo();

    });
});
```

When i call `Dashboard.getUserInfo()` the method gets called find, but the `Connect()` method never fires in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong...  as soon as I added a method like this:

```
$(function () {
//Create the proxy
var Dashboard = $.connection.dashboard;

Dashboard.someMethod = function(message){
}

$.connection.hub.start(function () {
    Dashboard.getUserInfo();

});
});
```

My `Connect()` function started firing, didnt know you needed a client function in there to activate the connect.

Comment: Yes you need at least one subscription. It's "optimized" so you don't end up subscribing to hubs you don't need to.

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this one too. Perhaps this could be added to the wiki?